# Caching column_property in sqlalchemy model via dogpile

Tags: python, caching, redis, sqlalchemy, dogpile.cache

I wonder if there is a chance to cache `column_property` using dogpile.

This is my code:

```
A.some_count = column_property(
  select([func.count()])
    .where(and_(B.__table__.c.a_id == A.__table__.c.id,
                B.__table__.c.c_id == C.__table__.c.id))  
    .correlate(A.__table__, C.__table__)
    .as_scalar()
    .label('some_count'),
  deferred=True)
```

Do anybody know how to do that? Any kind of caching would be good either with time stamp or invalidate.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to cache the property so that subsequent fetches are avoided after expiring or for new instances of `A` having the same identity?

Comment: I would like to cache this property per instance of class A @IljaEverilä

Comment: But an instance already keeps the value around, once fetched.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I think you don't understand me. So imagine situation that I have web application and I want cache this property in dogpile, because I don't want to query it, every time when I reload a page. For example cache it and reload every 1 hour. Is it possible?